# Different permutations of n identical groups with sizes a, b, and c.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My question is trying to solve how many paths there are from $(x,y)$ to $(tx, ty)$ 3 possible moves are allowed at each step: 
increment $x$ by $1$ 
increment $x$ by $2$ 
increment $y$ by $1$

I know that if only increments of 1 were allowed, then the solution is just:

$$\frac{((tx - x) + (ty - y))!}{((tx - x)!*(ty - y)!)}$$

But the incrementing x by two is really throwing me. Any hints would  be appreciated. I'm not looking for the solution, just something to help me not be stumped.

Comment: You could try using a recurrence relation: if $a_(x,y)$ is the number of paths from $(x,y)$ to $(tx, ty)$, then it is equal to $a_(x-1,y) + a_(x,y-1) + a_(x-2,y)$.